# Custom pattern for grunt-usemin poster attribute html video tag

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, grunt-usemin

I'm currently using yeoman and the grunt-usemin task to revved my assets. However, since I'm using the video tag, usemin ignores the `poster` attribute.

E.g.

```
<video id="video-1" poster="/images/awesomeFeature.png">
  <source src="..."/>
</video>
```

After grunt-usemin I would expect the following:

```
<video id="video-1" poster="/images/ch6k8.awesomeFeature.png">
  <source src="..."/>
</video>
```

I tried using the documented `patterns` option documented [here](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/tree/v2.0#patterns), such as the following:

```
usemin: {
    options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= cw.dist %>'],
        patterns: {
          html: [[/poster="([^"]*")/, 'Replacing reference to posters']]
        }
    },
    html: ['<%= cw.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
    css: ['<%= cw.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
}
```

However, it doesn't work. [Examples](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/blob/master/test/test-usemin.js#L233) from the grunt-usemin repository work with javascript, but I can't seem to make them work with HTML. Previous [issues](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/100) point that this is the right direction, but can't seem to find a working example. Ideas?

Comment: Added a PR with the solution - https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/pull/254

Answer (score 1):

This issue has some details
https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/164

The gist is that you may need to alter usemin code. The issue has been closed, but I'm not sure the code as been fixed in the project.

Comment: It's on the same page, that's for sure. I'll check the regex file, and if I can fix it I'll do a PR.

Comment: Added a PR with the solution to be supported within `grunt-usemin`, see my comment.